# Solr: Normalize date field

Tags: solr

I am new to apache solr and exploring some use cases that could potentially be applicable for my application.
In one of the use case, I have multiple mongodb instances pushing data to solr via mongo-connector. I am able to do so by running two instance of mongo-connector with two different mongo instance and using same solr core.

My question is: How do I handle a situation where I have a field in mongo-collection, say "startTime" which is of Date type in one mongo instance and another is treating it as long. I want this field to be treated as long type in solr. Does solr provide any sort of auto conversion or I will have to write my analyzer?

Comment: Analyzers are invoked on text fields - so that won't help if you expect to use it in a long field. How about an [update request chain](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/update-request-processors.html)? The [StatelessScriptUpdateProcessor](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory.html) allows you to inject Javascript code into the indexing process to change field values.

Comment: Thank you MatsLindh for the pointer.. Let me try this today and will update soon.

Comment: @MatsLindh: request chain worked out for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want both values to normalize to the same form, you should do that in the UpdateRequestProcessor ([defined in solrconfig.xml](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/update-request-processors.html)). There is [quite a number of them](http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/) for various purposes, including date parsing. In fact, the schemaless mode is implemented by a chain of URPs, so that's [an example you can review](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/7.3.0/solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf/solrconfig.xml#L1192).

To process different Mongo instances in different ways, you can just define separate [Update Request Handler](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/requesthandlers-and-searchcomponents-in-solrconfig.html) endpoints (in solrconfig.xml again) and setup different processing for those. Use shared definitions to avoid duplicating what's common (using *processor* reference as in the schemaless definition linked above).

It may be more useful to normalize to dates rather than back from dates, as Solr allows more interesting searches that way, such as [Date Math](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/working-with-dates.html).

Comment: Thank you @Alexandre. +1 for neat explanation (especially for the shared definition). I implemented a simple Update Request Handler and it's exactly what I was looking for. However, would you mind explaining how can I map different mongo instances with different request handlers?

Comment: '<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="df">text</str>
    <str name="wt">json</str>
    <long name="commitWithin">1000</long>
    <str name="update.chain">normalizeField</str>
  </lst>
 </requestHandler>
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="normalizeField">
      <processor class="customProcessor" />
      <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
      <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
   </updateRequestProcessorChain>'

Comment: name="/update" - that's part of the URL you send your Mongo data to. So, you just create several request handlers with different names and different definitions. Give each Mongo a different end-point.